# Javascript audio support in browsers - an idiosyncrasy

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I've looked through this site and various others and can't find any explanation of, nor any solution for, this idiosyncrasy.

Despite what is said on these various sites, Javascript and HTML5 DOM audio do not appear to be working across all browsers as has been indicated in the various discussions on the various sites.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<audio id="buttonAudio" src="buttonClick.wav"></audio>

<button onclick="newGame00()">New Game 00</button>
<button onclick="newGame01()">New Game 01</button>
<button onclick="newGame02()">New Game 02</button>
<button onclick="newGame03()">New Game 03</button>
<button onclick="newGame04()">New Game 04</button>
<button onclick="newGame05()">New Game 05</button>
<button onclick="newGame06()">New Game 06</button>

<script>

// W3 Schools (https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp) says Firefox has
//   supported HTML5 audio since version 3.5, and Internet Explorer has supported
//   it since version 9.0.

// W3 Schools also (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_audio_play.asp) says 
//   Firefox supports the HTML5 DOM Audio object, and Internet Explorer has done
//   so since version 9.0. In fact, this W3 Schools page specifically recommends
//   the method I've implemented via the "New Game 06" button.

// Nevertheless:

// I've tried all six of these methods for getting a button click in javascript.
//   None of them work in version 61.0.1 (64-bit) of Mozilla Firefox.
//   None of them work in version 11.0.9600.19080 of Internet Explorer.
//   All six of them work in version 41.16299.371.0 of Edge.
//   All six of them work in version 67.0.3396.99 (64-bit) of Google Chrome.
//   All six of them work in version 54.0.2952.64 of Opera.
//   All six of them work in version 19.0.2.0 (32-bit) of Slimjet.

var buttonClick = new Audio("buttonClick.wav");

var x = document.getElementById('buttonAudio');

function newGame00() {
    buttonClick.play();
}

function newGame01() {
    buttonAudio.play();
}

function newGame02() {
    doit02();
}

function newGame03() {
    doit03();
}

function newGame04() {
    document.getElementById('buttonAudio').play();
}

function newGame05() {
    doit05();
}

function newGame06() {
    x.play();
}

async function doit02() {
    buttonClick.play();
}

async function doit03() {
    buttonAudio.play();
}

async function doit05() {
    document.getElementById('buttonAudio').play();
}

</script>
</body>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is inside this .wav container? Definitely works for me on FF: https://jsfiddle.net/ko3ru7vf/

Comment: Hmmm. It's a simple click sound generated by Audacity 2.1.0. I'd be suspicious of it too, if it weren't for the fact that it works fine in all those other browsers. Since yesterday, I've also tried it with buttonClick.mp3 and buttonClick.ogg, both with the same results. This afternoon, I'll go try it in Firefox on one of my library's computers and see what happens. Maybe I need to reinstall Firefox ??

Comment: Meanwhile, if you wish, you can directly try my code at http://www.bds-soft.com/NewSite/clickTest.html . Maybe there's something wrong with my code? Please ignore the rest of the NewSite - it's ALL still under construction.

Comment: But, nope: At one of our local library's computers, it worked fine on version 41.16299.547.0 of Edge and version 67.0.3396.99 of Chrome; but not on version 61.0.1 of Firefox nor on version 11.547.16299.0 of Internet Explorer.

Comment: I found a Firefox suggestion at https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/i-cant-play-audio-remote-desktop-connection but it did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

cor-el, the moderator of the Mozilla support forum, solved this for me. Firefox doesn't support all .wav options. Audacity had saved it at 44100Hz. Per his suggestion, I re-did it at 48000Hz.

Now it works in Firefox, as well as continuing to work in Edge, Chrome, Opera, and Slimjet.

Of course, it still doesn't work in IE. (sigh). Apparently, IE simply doesn't support .wav files. Nor, it would seem, does it support .mp3 or .ogg files.